# How to use the function variables (x and y) in the plot title that the function creates

Tags: r, function, plot, title

I'm working on creating a function that graphs linear regressions and residuals. I've created the body of the function, but I would like to add more details to the plot it produces, such as a title and axis labels. Specifically, I want to have the title of the plot be the variables which were input into the function, like this: "y by x" where y and x are the name which was input into the function. I've tried using paste() and print() to accomplish this, but it hasn't been successful.
Also, I've just been using rnorm(10) to produce values for x and y, but I still want the title to reflect whatever I input into the function, so the title should be "rnorm(10) by rnorm(10)" but instead it turns out as "print(y) by print(x)". Any suggestions on the correct code to use to accomplish this?

```
reslines <- function(x,y) 
{
x <- x
y <- y
plot(y~x, pch=20, col=1, title=print(y) by print(x))
lm.xy <- lm(y~x)
abline(lm.xy)
segments(x0 = x, y0 = y, y1 = predict(lm.xy), col = 130)
summary(lm.xy)
}

reslines(rnorm(10,rnorm(10))
```

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Substitutions might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 reslines <- function(x, y) {
 # x <- x
 # y <- y
 plot(y ~ x, pch = 20, col = 1, main = paste(c(substitute(y), "by", substitute(x)), collapse = " "))
 lm.xy <- lm(y ~ x)
 abline(lm.xy)
 segments(x0 = x, y0 = y, y1 = predict(lm.xy), col = 130)
 summary(lm.xy)
}

reslines(rnorm(10), rnorm(10))
```